# How to express $n$ unknown variables in a system with $n-1$ equations

Tags: systems-of-equations, closed-form, recursive-algorithms

I have a system of $n-1$ equations which have $n$ unknown variables, as follows:
\begin{align}
&\text{Equation $1$}  &&x_1A_{1,1}+...+x_nA_{1,n}=0\\
& \hspace{1cm}\vdots && \hspace{2cm}\vdots\\
&\text{Equation $n-1$} &&x_1A_{n-1,1}+...+x_nA_{n-1,n}=0
\end{align}
As an example, if $n=2$, we have a single equation:
$$ x_1A_{1,1}+x_2A_{1,2}=0 \rightarrow x_1=-\frac{x_2A_{1,2}}{A_{1,1}}$$ and we have infinitive possible solutions for $x_2$.

I am trying to find a generic expression for the $x$ values for any value of $n$, probably this will be some recursive formula. Any suggestions on how to solve this are welcome.

Comment: You aren't really going to be able to do this in the form you'd like, any more than you'd be able to do it if you had $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns.

Comment: Because you have one more unknown than equations, you'll need to treat one of your unknowns as a constant, and solve for the others in terms of it. The "generic" form of the solution is known as [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). But there are more efficient ways of doing the actual calculations.